# Microsoft CRM 2016 Chart swap X and Y Axis

Tags: charts, customization, crm, axis, swap

Is there an easy way to swap the charts X and Y axis in the XML or CRM? Can I just swap the category and the measure?

Here is the Chart how it looks at this time:
[image]

Also Here is the whole XML code. I couldn't find a possibility to simply swap the  and  tag

```
    <visualization>
  <visualizationid>{27260A73-3293-E311-A4C8-000C29E59B89}</visualizationid>
  <name>Skill Gap</name>
  <primaryentitytypecode>xxx_skill_level</primaryentitytypecode>
  <datadescription>
    <datadefinition>
      <fetchcollection>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
          <entity name="xxx_skill_level">
            <attribute groupby="true" alias="Skill" name="xxx_skill_level_skill_id" />
            <link-entity name="xxx_skill_grade" from="xxx_skill_gradeid" to="xxx_skill_level_grade_required" link-type="outer">
              <attribute alias="RequiredGrade" name="xxx_rating" aggregate="max" />
            </link-entity>
            <link-entity name="xxx_skill_grade" from="xxx_skill_gradeid" to="xxx_skill_level_grade_actual" link-type="outer">
              <attribute alias="ActualGrade" name="xxx_rating" aggregate="max" />
            </link-entity>
          </entity>
        </fetch>
      </fetchcollection>
      <categorycollection>
        <category alias="Skill">
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="RequiredGrade" />
          </measurecollection>
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="ActualGrade" />
          </measurecollection>
        </category>
      </categorycollection>
    </datadefinition>
  </datadescription>
  <presentationdescription>
    <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="">
      <Series>
        <Series ChartType="Line" Name="o:xxx_chart_translations,693100015" Color="222,130,41" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" MarkerStyle="Square" MarkerSize="9" MarkerColor="222,130,41" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40">
          <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
        </Series>
        <Series ChartType="Line" Name="o:xxx_chart_translations,693100016" Color="66,166,66" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" MarkerStyle="Square" MarkerSize="9" MarkerColor="66,166,66" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40">
          <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
        </Series>
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea BorderColor="White" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
          <AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
            <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
            <MajorGrid LineColor="Transparent" />
            <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
          </AxisX>
          <AxisY LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
            <MajorGrid LineColor="239, 242, 246" />
            <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
            <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
          </AxisY>
        </ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      <Titles>
        <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59"></Title>
      </Titles>
      <Legends>
        <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="bottom" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
      </Legends>
    </Chart>
  </presentationdescription>
  <isdefault>false</isdefault>
</visualization>
```